# Is an email private or confidential just because we say so in Canada?

Tags: privacy, freedom-of-speech, email, confidentiality

I received an email that claimed that its contents were confidential and private, and not to be shared. Sometimes people have automatic privacy notices at the footers of their emails, which is not the case here, and there are related questions [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/12081/does-a-boilerplate-this-email-is-private-message-have-any-legal-force) and [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/577/what-is-the-value-in-adding-an-email-confidentiality-notice) on this but unfortunately doesn't mention Canadian law. I am also quite sure that I have not signed any non-disclosure agreement on this subject. Upon reviewing the contents of this email, I did not see any merit to calling any of its contents *confidential* or *private*.

I don't have any intentions of sharing the contents of the email at this time, but I would like to know my rights if I felt it was important to contradict the explicit wishes of such an email to keep information private. Can someone (within the jurisdiction of Canada) silence me on a topic just because they declared it was confidential or private? Certainly not for anything criminal, but that is a pretty low bar to set.

> Note: I am not asking for official legal advice, but layperson explanations of primary or secondary sources on Canadian law would be welcome.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Thank you for looking into the customs of law.se. When someone answers this question somewhere on law.se in reference to Canada's legal jurisdiction on another post, I will happily close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: From meta: "Only moderators can merge questions. If you believe a question should be merged, first vote or recommend closure flag to close it as a duplicate, and wait until the question gets closed as a duplicate. Once it is (or if it already is), flag the question for moderator attention, clearly explaining that the question should be merged and that it fits the guidelines in the above section."